# Python SMTP Emails Showing Both Plain and HTML Versions

Tags: python, email, smtp, sendgrid

Sending an smtp email, and when I receive the email it shows the plain text version and the html version back to back. The point of this is to take incoming email dicts from Sendgrid and then send them to another user. The 'message' object referenced in the code is the dict Sendgrid posts to my endpoint.

Here is what I'm seeing:

```
    test

Me
Signature

    test

Me
Signature
```

Here is the string I am sending to the mailServer:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============5453410005537724489=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: me+test@domain.com
From: Me <me@domain.com>
Subject: test
reply-to: Original Sender <sender@theirdomain.com>

--===============5453410005537724489==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    test

Me
Signature




--===============5453410005537724489==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=us-ascii"></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;" class=""><span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre">    </span>test<br class=""><div apple-content-edited="true" class="">
<span>Me</span><br><span>Signature</span>
</div>
<br class=""></body></html>
--===============5453410005537724489==--
```

Lastly, here is the Python I am using to send the email:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

subject = message.get('subject', 'No Subject')
text = message.get('text', None)
html = message.get('html', None)
to = message.get('to')
cc = message.get('cc', None)
reply_to = message.get('from')

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['To'] = 'me+test@domcin.com'
msg['From'] = 'me@domain.com'
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.add_header('reply-to', reply_to)

toaddrs = msg['To']
if cc is not None:
    msg['CC'] = ', '.join(cc)
    toaddrs += ', ' + msg['CC']

if text is not None:
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'plain'))
else:
    msg.attach(MIMEText('No plain text for this email', 'plain'))

if html is not None:
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'html'))

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)
mailServer.sendmail(GMAIL_USERNAME, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
mailServer.quit()
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've specified `multipart/mixed` content, which means that the parts are independent messages, and should all be shown, in exactly the order included.

You want `multipart/alternative`, which means the parts are alternative versions of the same message, and only the last one whose content-type the receiver can understand should be shown.

In other words:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative) has a nice explanation of the different multipart subtypes, but for the official definition, turn to [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046):

> **5.1.3.  Mixed Subtype**

> The "mixed" subtype of "multipart" is intended for use when the body
> parts are independent and need to be bundled in a particular order.
> Any "multipart" subtypes that an implementation does not recognize
> must be treated as being of subtype "mixed".

> **5.1.4.  Alternative Subtype**

> The "multipart/alternative" type is syntactically identical to
> "multipart/mixed", but the semantics are different.  In particular,
> each of the body parts is an "alternative" version of the same
> information.

> Systems should recognize that the content of the various parts are
> interchangeable.  Systems should choose the "best" type based on the
> local environment and references, in some cases even through user
> interaction.  As with "multipart/mixed", the order of body parts is
> significant.  In this case, the alternatives appear in an order of
> increasing faithfulness to the original content.  In general, the
> best choice is the LAST part of a type supported by the recipient
> system's local environment.

> "Multipart/alternative" may be used, for example, to send a message
> in a fancy text format in such a way that it can easily be displayed
> anywhere…